# Keeping same number of columns at cross tab report

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crosstab

I have a `cross-tab` report which similar to this 
[image]

Problem is when there are no data to one month that column won't appear in the report. I would like to keep the same number of column even there are empty values for the row data.
Is it possible to achieve in `cross-tab` reports??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem more with the underlying dataset. You have two options:

- Modify your query to always return data even for "empty" groups
- Hardcode the columns into the cross-tab

Option 1 is probably the best approach. Take a look at this similar question: [Handling non existent values in sql query expression for ssrs chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691824/handling-non-existent-values-in-sql-query-expression-for-ssrs-chart/9692399#9692399)

Comment: Yes, anyway it is not possible to hardcore column since the column data (which is date pereoid) is a parameter which user select